# How to reduce the time complexity of this code to find the maximum number of consecutive 1's in a binary array?

Tags: c++, data-structures

The following code gives the right output for finding the maximum number of consecutive 1's in a binary array. But time limit exceeds while compiling. Is there any where to reduce the time complexity of this code?

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(vector<int>& nums) {
       int new_count = 0, count = 0; 
       if (find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 1) == nums.end())
           return 0;     
        for(int i=0; i<nums.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j=i; j<nums.size()-1; j++)
            {
                if(nums[j] == 1 && nums[j+1] == 1)
                    count++;
                else
                    break;
            }
            new_count = max(new_count, count+1);
            count = 0;
        }
        return new_count;  
}
};
```

Comment: What time limit is exceeded? Runtime or compile time?

Comment: Hint: It can be done in a single pass over the array, with only one index variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is of time complexity `O(N^2)`, where `N` is the size of `nums`.

The following one is a `O(N)` solution which get the answer in a single pass.

```
class Solution {
 public:
  int findMaxConsecutiveOnes(vector<int>& nums) {
    int count = 0, max_count = 0;
    for (auto num: nums) {
      if (num == 1) {
        count += 1;
      } else {
        max_count = max(count, max_count);
        count = 0;
      }
    }
    return max(count, max_count);
  }
};
```